# Conexion a carpeta compartida con autenticación

Tags: java, windows

Estoy tratando de conectarme de manera remota a unas carpetas compartidas que están en diferentes servidores. Encontré el método con las librerías jcifs. La cual me funciona muy bien con una de las carpetas compartidas. Sin embargo cuando intento hacer lo mismo con la otra me arroja la siguiente excepción:

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbException: 
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.readn(Transport.java:29)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.peekKey(SmbTransport.java:351)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:267)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:298)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:223)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:239)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.connect(SmbTransport.java:288)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:132)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:791)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:761)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1251)
```

El código que utilizo en mi prueba luce algo así:

```
String url = "smb://x.x.x.x/carpeta/";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("dominio", "usuario", "contraseña");
    SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
    if(dir.exists()) {
        System.out.println("existe");
    }
```

¿Hay alguien a quien le haya ocurrido lo mismo? Cabe mencionar que encontré otro metodo que si funciona con la carpeta con error, pero falla con la otra.

Comment: Tu código para autenticarte en la carpeta de red está bien. El problema que tienes es montando el socket. Qué versión de Java estás usando? Yo procuraría usar al menos Java8. Así mismo, puede que haya líos en la cantidad de memoria que le asignas al heap (revisa si puedes asignarle más). Por último, puede ser simplemente culpa del servidor y no hay mucho que hacer aparte de aumentar el socket timeout

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, muchas gracias por tu comentario. Pues es java 8. Te cuento que descargue otra versión de jcifs llamada jcifs-ng. Este usa un método de conexión algo distinto pero funcionó para ambas carpetas.

Comment: Significa que, posiblemente, el protocolo para conectarse cambió y jcifs no soporta la versión de tu servidor :O